# create a user in postgres docker container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a django app in docker container, but I do not know how to create a user in postgres container that django uses. I guess that is why when I start it (by `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate`) it tells me `database_1 | FATAL: role "my_user" does not exist`.
What am I doing wrong?

`docker-compose.yaml` right now looks like:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

  database:
    image: postgres:9.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "django_db"
      POSTGRES_USER: "my_user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "my_password"
      POSTGRES_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "database:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    tmpfs:
      - "/tmp"
      - "/run"
    networks:
      db-net:

  django:
    build: ./
    image: django:latest
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://my_user:my_pass@database/django_db"

    ports:
      - 7445:80
```

Comment: try to clean `/var/lib/postgresql/data` directory and restart cluster.

Comment: Your services might be starting at the same time so django tries to connect before the progres database created the user. https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your `docker-compose.yml` I would say that you have successfully  created the user *my_user* in your database. You can verify that by running `docker exec -ti project_database_1 psql -U my_user -d django_db` on your host.

I suggest you take a look at [`cookiecutter-django`](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django). You can find there a complete docker setup including the solved problem [JodyT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1737862/jodyt) mentioned about starting `Django` before the `postgres` container is actually ready.

It's from the authors of the book [two scopes of django](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/products/two-scoops-of-django-1-11) which is also worth a read.